# why a translucent activity shows another non-translucent activity?

Tags: java, android, layout, android-activity, android-fragments

this is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.stopcall.app" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >



        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ItemDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name=".activities.PopupActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.example.stopcall.app.OutgoingCallReceiver" >
            <!--<intent-filter>-->
                <!--<action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />-->
                <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />-->
            <!--</intent-filter>-->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I start my application. `ItemDetailActivity` is displayed.

Then i pause it (make it hidden in the tasks stack).

I use the dialer that triggers `PopupActivity` (translucent) and `PopupFragment` on it.

I want to see the fragment only, floating on the dialer when created.

That's why I added `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">`

however when the fragment is displayed, all the sudden the `ItemDetailActivity` is brought from the stack and appears as the background.

How can I avoid this? meaning only the fragment will be seen on top of the dialer which triggered it?

**Edit**

As I mentioned. The fragment shows its activity it's just transparent. The problem is that another unrelated activity of my app suddenly appears form the task stack.

my final goal is to show a popup on the dialer. can it be done?

**Edit**

my receiver start the new transparent activity with the popup fragment.

```
    @Override
    protected void handleReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
..

                Intent i = new Intent(context, PopupActivity.class);
                i.putExtra(Constants.DIALED_PHONE, phoneDal.getItem(phoneNumber));
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(i);
                setResultData(null);
```

and yet the popup appears with transparent activity and aslo a sibling activity that was previously shown.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is displaying the transparent activity will make the other activity visible blow the it. It is because these activities are in the same task stack.

You should try to start you activity with flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` or `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

```
/**
 * If set, this activity will become the start of a new task on this
 * history stack.  A task (from the activity that started it to the
 * next task activity) defines an atomic group of activities that the
 * user can move to.  Tasks can be moved to the foreground and background;
 * all of the activities inside of a particular task always remain in
 * the same order.  See
 * <a href="{@docRoot}guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html">Tasks and Back
 * Stack</a> for more information about tasks.
 *
 * <p>This flag is generally used by activities that want
 * to present a "launcher" style behavior: they give the user a list of
 * separate things that can be done, which otherwise run completely
 * independently of the activity launching them.
 *
 * <p>When using this flag, if a task is already running for the activity
 * you are now starting, then a new activity will not be started; instead,
 * the current task will simply be brought to the front of the screen with
 * the state it was last in.  See {@link #FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK} for a flag
 * to disable this behavior.
 *
 * <p>This flag can not be used when the caller is requesting a result from
 * the activity being launched.
 */
public static final int FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK = 0x10000000;


/**
 * If set in an Intent passed to {@link Context#startActivity Context.startActivity()},
 * this flag will cause any existing task that would be associated with the
 * activity to be cleared before the activity is started.  That is, the activity
 * becomes the new root of an otherwise empty task, and any old activities
 * are finished.  This can only be used in conjunction with {@link #FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK}.
 */
public static final int FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK = 0X00008000;
```

If you want to display your UI on top of phone app.

The best way to do this is to use a floating window. Which is also a very popular technology for displaying dialog like GUI on top of other applications. You could Google it for more information, the followings are some basic operations.

```
mWindowManager = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
mWindowManager.addView(mView, mParams); //add the floating view
mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mView, mParams); //update layout parameters (size/position)
mWindowManager.removeView(mView); //remote the floating view
```

Comment: `You can not just show a fragment without its activity.` I want to show the activity. Its transparent. The problem is that i see another activity which is not of that fragment, but was stored in the same task stack. is my situation clear?

Comment: As I mentioned. The fragment shows its activity it's just transparent. The problem is that another unrelated activity of my app suddenly appears form the task stack.

my final goal is to show a popup on the dialer. can it be done?

Comment: what does `remote the floating view` practically mean?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question before, see edited answer.

Comment: I have tried and yet the same result. see my edited q